# Unable to simulate iOS application on my device. "Unable to verify APP"

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to build and simulate my app from xcode to my device but I'm struggling with an error that always show up when I run my application.

Error:

```
Could not launch “AppName” Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain Code: 3 Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch org.reactjs.native.example.AppName because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
```

When I tap the app button on my phone it says:

```
"Unable to verify app. An internet connection is required to verify the trust of the developer ... This app will not be available until verified."
```

I already trusted the developer on Settings > General > VPN & Device Management but even when I trust it the app still saying "Not verified"

My app runs normally on xcode simulator.

iOS version: 16.2 
Xcode version: 14.1 
macOS: Ventura 13.0.1

I already trusted the developer on Settings > General > VPN & Device Management but even when I trust it the app still saying "Not verified"

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Following.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it. I went into ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and cleared the old profiles. At the same time I restarted my iOS device. Upon restart I was able to go to preferences, and trust the development cert, and also verify the app successfully. I was able to run it from Xcode after this.

Comment: This was the solution!